# Flutter - how to specific Card height

Tags: flutter

```
class CardContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      height: 40,
      child: Card(
        semanticContainer: true,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Test Campaign',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  LineButton(
                    onPress: () => null,
                    label: 'View',
                    height: 30,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have this piece of code that outputs this. Now this part it's only the content inside the tabs.

[image]

As you can see the Card goes all the way down. I want that Card to be about 50 pixel in height. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You just wrap your container just sniglechildScrollView.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              height: 80,
              child: Card(
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Test Campaign',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                           LineButton(
                    onPress: () => null,
                    label: 'View',
                    height: 30,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
        
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: missing singleChildScrollView in your code

Comment: Yeah I can see that. I was looking more for the reason why, so I can learn from my mistake.